# How to subscribe subject to observable function with params

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subject

I have function with arbitrary params of observable that is doing some job. 
I want to subscribe to it a subject that have other some subscription (for make all triggered for the functions called).

I can't find the way to do it right.

My service :

```
//The method of the observable 
addProduct2(product: Product) {     
  delete product.id;
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/createProduct';
  return this.http.post<Product>(url, product);
}
```

I want that this will work :

```
getProductsEvent:Subject<Product> = new Subject();

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private currentRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  //....
  this.addProduct2.subscribe(this.getProductsEvent);
}
```

I am getting this compiling error :

> ERROR in
>   src/app/components/products-feature/data-service.service.ts(42,22):
>   error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(product:
>   Product) => Observable'.

and in the logs :

> AppComponent.html:3 ERROR TypeError: this.addProduct2.subscribe is not
>   a function
>       at new DataServiceService (data-service.service.ts:42)...

How can I achieve it right? What's I'm missing?

remember that I can't invoke

```
this.addProduct2().subscribe...;
```

because it's have a params, and I don't know what params it will get.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve here. Do you want to emit a value in `getProductsEvent` when the http reponse is returned?

Comment: Yeah, actually the the getProductsEvent is common subject that I am using for pass data among some components.
I want to insert it this addProduct action for it will do the subscribers again (and refresh the data after post) . @KurtHamilton

Comment: I suggest you work on improving the quality of your questions. People are downvoting your and voting to close. I understand not everyone is fluent in English, but you could start with properly formatting your code. People are more willing to help if they see you put serious effort in your question. Also read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I improved the formatting for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to emit an event every time a new product is created you have to call next on your productsEvent `Subject`.

```
private productEvent: Subject<Product> = new Subject(); 

public getProductsEvent(); Subject<Product> {
  return this.productEvent;
}

public addProduct(product: Product): Observable<Product> {
  delete product.id;
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080/createProduct';
  return this.http.post<Product>(url, product).pipe(
    tap((product: Product) => this.productEvent.next(product)),
  );
}
```

I used a pipe and the pipable tap operator to call next after the new product is returned from your http post request. The `addProduct` method returns an observable that means nothing will happen until you subscribe to it.

- Read more on [the rxjs pipe and pipable operators here in the documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators)
- Read more specifically on the tap operator [here in the documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap)

With everything setup like this you can use it as follows:

Somewhere you can add a product by calling the method and subscribing.

```
addProduct(data).subscribe();
```

And anywhere where you subscribed to the event you will be notified:

```
getProductsEvent().subscribe((addedProduct: Product) => {
  // Do something with the added product
  console.log(addedProduct)
});
```

---

**Note** *I kept the types like in your question, but I wonder if the type of the data you post `Product` is the same as the type of the response, also `Product` but I guess you know your object types best, so I left it as is.*

Comment: Thanks, I have learned about Observable and Subjects, and I've tried to subscribe the subject to observable that make get (on the service) and from there to subscribe event of getData to that at the component of the list. 
And at the addProduct comp I want that after the post returned successfully, just to make again call to the subject(that will trigger the get observable), for the data will be updated.

Apparently it doesn't work,  I missing something at the using of subjects inside components, I just tried to make it simple,I assume I should pass on the observable with angular tutorial

Comment: @lingar If you look at your code `this.addProduct2` is a function, the `addProduct` function. `this.addProduct`is not an `Observable`instance. So you cannot subscribe to it...